# zsh: command not found: blitz

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, blitz.js

I installed blitz like this `yarn global add blitz` but then when I try to create a new project `blitz new myApp` I get this error `zsh: command not found: blitz`.

I guess I have to add something to my `$HOME/.zshrc` file but I don't know what.

How can I fix this?

This is my `$HOME/.zshrc`:

```
export ZSH="/Users/user/.oh-my-zsh"


ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"


plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Comment: You have to add the path your environment `PATH` variable. What's the path to the executable? Where are packets installed? I added the path in `~/.profile` instead of `~/.zshrc`

Comment: I don't have a `.profile` file.  What's the path to the executable? I don't know, the default?

Comment: If I do `echo $PATH` I get: 
`/Users/user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`. Is this what you mean @jabaa?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` are already in your `PATH`. This is MacOS. I was assuming you're using Linux. I don't know where global NPM packages are installed on your system. `npm config get prefix` could give you the path.

Comment: @jabaa : This recommendation does not make much sense. zsh does not process ~/.profile on startup. A good place to put the PATH settings would be `~/.zshenv`, since this file is read by interactive **and** non-interactive zsh.

Comment: @saralance : I don't see in the .zshrc you posted, that you would set up the PATH. See also my comment to jabaa on that matter.

Comment: @jabaa : According to the man-page, this applies only to a zsh executed in _sh_ and _ksh_ compatibility mode. This is explained in the paragraph _COMPATIBILITY_. If you read the section _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_ in the man-page, you will see that they don't mention `.profile`.

Answer (score 2):

I end up using `npm install -g blitz --legacy-peer-deps` to install it.